# How to show errors in required files node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

If I have errors in my basic file - `index.js`, I can see if I have some mistake. For example, if I type 
`"console.log(22)l"` instead of `"console.log(22);"`, I'll get an error.

But if I have repeated the same mistake in required file, the script just hangs and I don't see some errors in my terminal.
How to make Node.js show errors in all files?

Comment: I think you are wrong about that. Errors do get shown for required files. I would imagine that there is another cause for the hang.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the below syntax to log your errors,as this is the standard mentioned in nodejs documentation

```
request.log(['error'], err.stack);
```

Comment: This is not standard.

Comment: Can you tell me then which is standard??

Comment: `console.log()` and `console.error()` are part of the Node.js standard library, if you want more elaborate logging (which isn't really the issue here) you need to use a third-party module like `winston` or `bunyan`.